# Android exo player need internet for playing cached media

Tags: android, kotlin, exoplayer

Hello guys I'm developing an android application that user can download medias with exo player. everything is ok and media is playing without internet but when user delete a media other downloaded media needs internet to render at first and after that media is playing without internet. the error is:
[image]

this is how a media delete:

```
DemoUtil.getDownloadManager(this).removeDownload(download.request.id)
```

and in player this is how I create my media(it's a hls.)

```
val downloadRequest = DemoUtil.getDownloadTracker(this).getDownloadRequest(Uri.parse(offlineVideoLink))

hlsMediaSource = downloadRequest?.let { DownloadHelper.createMediaSource(it, dataSourceFactory) }
```

dataSourceFactory define like this:

```
    public static synchronized DataSource.Factory getDataSourceFactory(Context context) {
        if (dataSourceFactory == null) {
            context = context.getApplicationContext();
            DefaultDataSource.Factory upstreamFactory =
                    new DefaultDataSource.Factory(context, getHttpDataSourceFactory());
            dataSourceFactory = buildReadOnlyCacheDataSource(upstreamFactory, getDownloadCache(context));
        }
        return dataSourceFactory;
    }
```

Comment: if you need more information please let me know.

Comment: How you are creating `dataSourceFactory` ? Kindly share the code

Comment: @KamalNayan I write it for you.

Comment: I'm following this sample: https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/release-v2/demos/main/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer2/demo/DemoUtil.java

Comment: And `HLSMediaSource` ?

Comment: @KamalNayan from DownloadHelper.createMediaSource(). and when I debug it the Uri and m3u8 path and media id is ok.

Comment: could you please code of function `createMediaSource\`

Comment: @KamalNayan public static MediaSource createMediaSource( DownloadRequest downloadRequest, DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory) { return createMediaSource(downloadRequest, dataSourceFactory, /* drmSessionManager= */ null); }